# Replacement expressions

Tags: list-manipulation, expression-manipulation

I have the following expressions:

```
R[1, 1] R[2, 1] R[3, 1] R[4, 1] 
sum[FF[3, ak[1] - ak[2], 1], EE[2, ak[2] - ak[3], 0], EE[2, ak[3] - ak[4], 0]]
```

By what procedure can I convert such expressions into expression:

```
sum[R[1, 1], FF[3, ak[2] - ak[2], 1], R[2, 1] , EE[2, ak[2] - ak[3], 0], R[3, 1] , EE[2, ak[3] - ak[4], 0] , R[4, 1]]
```

Comment: Perhaps you should look at `Riffle`.

Answer (score 5):

```
expr = R[1, 1] R[2, 1] R[3, 1] R[4, 1] sum[FF[3, ak[1] - ak[2], 1], 
    EE[2, ak[2] - ak[3], 0], EE[2, ak[3] - ak[4], 0]];

expr /. a_ sum[b__] :> sum @@ Riffle[List @@ a, {b}]
```

> sum[R[1, 1], FF[3, ak[1] - ak[2], 1], R[2, 1], 
>    EE[2, ak[2] - ak[3], 0], R[3, 1], EE[2, ak[3] - ak[4], 0], R[4, 1]]